# How to change variable values from RecyclerView which are presented in this recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have the following situation: there is a recycler view on my screen. By default, it has 3 objects with empty variables. ViewHolder for this recycler view contains 2 `EditTexts`. And I need to make this recycler view in such way that each time the user enters something to the `EditText` this value also should be set to the corresponding variable of the object which belongs to this element. For example, there is an `EditText` where the user can enter the product name. This name should be added to EditText and also this name should be set as the value to the product.name variable. Here's the way how this screen looks now:

[image]

And here's the way how the adapter is implemented:

```
public class BillProductsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BillProductsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<StockItem> stockItems = new ArrayList<>();

    public BillProductsAdapter() {
        stockItems.add(new StockItem());
        stockItems.add(new StockItem());
        stockItems.add(new StockItem());
    }

    public void addRow() {
        stockItems.add(new StockItem());
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public List<StockItem> getStockItems() {
        return stockItems;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.bill_product_element, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return stockItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return R.layout.bill_product_element;
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        EditText name;
        EditText amount;

        ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_et);
            amount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.amount_et);

        }

    }

}
```

Method get stock items is executed when I click save button, so I tried to implement getting values logic in this method, but I couldn't get them as there is no `viewHolder` parameter here. So, I will appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
val viewHolder = mRecyclerView?.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position)
val amount = (viewHolder as ViewHolder).amount
amount.text = "6"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your `Edittext` value to your model in your `onBindViewholder`

```
holder.name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                Your_model.add(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```